# Save and Overwrite Variables in Python

Tags: python, variables, memory, overwrite

I need a little bit of help on overwriting python variables. Here's the best example I could give. IF someone opens up my program (in `.exe` or `.py`) and this were to come up:

```
var = 5
var = raw_input("Enter the new variable value: ") ##THE PERSON ENTERS 3
var = 3
```

Now, the user closes the file/program, next time they open it, they want the program to remember that `var = 3`, so it overwrote the `var = 5` with `var = 3`. I don't know if this is possible, but if it is, could you let me know?

To Clarify: I want my `.py` or `.exe` to remember that a variable was changed, and overwrite the old variable with the new one, so the next time they open the file, the variable is already changed.

Comment: You want to use file I/O, and explicitly write and read settings like these. Read a decent [Python tutorial for beginners](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers) first though.

Comment: I would suggest you progress a bit further in whatever python tutorial it is you're following. What you're looking to do is something called persistence, and there's a fair bit of basics ahead of you before you hit the parts about persistence.

Comment: @Jordan Do you want the PROGRAM or any OTHER FILE to keep the change ? If first case, the program will have to change it's own file, I beg it's possible but it will need some skills. If second case, it's persistence

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to somehow store the value, for example in a file, database, or with some service.

For example, using a [simple file](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#text-i-o):

```
import io,os
try:
    with io.open('~/.jordan_last_value', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        var = f.read()
except IOError: # Read failed
    var = raw_input('Enter the new variable value')

    # Save value to disk
    with io.open('~/.jordan_last_value', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       f.write(var)

print ('Current value is ' + var)
```

As you can see, this can be somewhat complex, so you may want to refresh your knowledge of [file handling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files). Also, this example code can just store strings.

If you want to be able to store more complex objects, you'll need a way to transform them from and to bytestrings first. Have a look at the [json](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) modules for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#example) module, json or whatever :P

Comment: Not a fan of giving people answers that are only literally correct and don't account for context. The context here in my opinion is the asker is missing a lot of programming basics and will just get frustrated jumping ahead to using a module like pickle. The asker's challenge is pedagogical in nature and not technical.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`pickle`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html?highlight=pickle#usage) module:

```
import pickle
try: # try to open the file
    with open('jordan_data.pkl', 'r+') as f:
        var = pickle.load(f)
except IOError: # if it doesn't exist, get new input
    var = raw_input("Enter the new variable value: ") # THE PERSON ENTERS 3
    with open('jordan_data.pkl', 'a+') as f: # 'a' will create the file if it doesn't exist
        pickle.dump(var, f) # then, save the file
```

Comment: You don't need `close` - the with statement does that already. Additionally, you should open the file in binary mode. Also, the renaming of `pickle` makes it unnecessarily hard to understand the code.